# Manipulating history of child window

Tags: javascript, window, back, forward

I'm trying to implement following functionality:

1. Page index.htm opens a new browser's window (e.g. using window.open), where the content of the new window is just pure image, let say page_067.jpg
2. I'd like an user who is on page_067.jpg can go to page_066.jpg using GO BACK browser's button or to page_068.jpg using GO FORWARD browser's button.

Alternatively, instead of page_067.jpg pure image file it could be something like page_067.htm with the image embedded.

What would be the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

[Popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event seems like what you are looking for. It could be triggered on back or forward button presses in the browser.

Comment: I guess it's impossible to set a history from the parent (index.htm) window, isn't it?